# Should site-wide special announcements appear above the action buttons

Tags: discussion, design, announcements

In this case i'm talking about the Steve Jobs one on http://stackoverflow.com. Note that I'm not debating whether it should be displayed or not.

I just feel that, since it has a coloured background and spans across the whole page, it should appear directly below the top 'bar' we have (that also has a coloured background and spans the whole page).

Having the top bar, then the action buttons, then the announcement bar, then the rest of the site doesn't look right to me.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: For such an exceptional circumstance, I'm sure you'll cope.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's probably designed like this intentionally - to make sure you eye is drawn to it because it stands out, then you'll hopefully read it.

It's designed for infrequent high-profile short-term important notices (such as planned outages, etc) that they need to be seen by as many people as possible, as soon as possible.

Making it easier to ignore by making it "fit" nicely with the rest of the page would actually be counter-productive to its intended purpose.